# Add a image uploader in the posts page backend

Tags: uploads

Can anyone suggest some idea as to how to add an image uploader in the post page backend just like the featured image.

Answer (score 0):

For custom fields in the backend (like an extra image or extra text) in a post backend we are using Advanced custom fields. This is for us the most easy way to add extra variables to the backend.

They also have a function especially for images or a gallery.

In your theme you can use `get_field('name_of_the_field')` in the loop of the post. Depending how the field is configured it returns an array, string of an id.